# '03 civic makes loud wobbly sound in engine when average going 40mph @ 2000rpm

Tags: noise

I dont understand what it could be. It only happens when I stay steady on the gas, and ranges from 25-45mph.  I can find feel it it vibrating in the gas peddle and steering wheel. Its a deepish sound, that can be imitated by a cat purring but really loud and clunky

Comment: This may be one of those rare times a video is in order?

Comment: Does it only happen with the gearbox in Drive? What if you shift into Neutral or D3 or 2?